# Where can I find Vishnu Yamala?

Tags: tantra, resource

Is Vishnu Yamala available either offline or online in any one of the English / Hindi languages.

Comment: I think it is out of print. Very rare to find it

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I wanted it. Is it available in Sanskrit anywhere?

Comment: i dont think so. Maybe archive.org